# JBoss 5.1 Scheduled Jobs Stops executing

Tags: java, jboss, jax-ws, quartz-scheduler

I have statefull quartz jobs, which are scheduled by JBoss scheduler. 
they fire every 20- 30  seconds.
4 of them are jax-ws clients. 1 is axis 2 client and 2 just http clients.

problem occurs only with jax-ws clients.
after some period of time they stack  in a middle of execution- when client is trying to initialize soap service:

```
        soap = new MyService(new URL(targetEndpoint), new QName(
        "http://www.catmancer.com/Service", "myservice"))
        .getMyServiceSoap();
```

and they are not started anymore, until server restart. even quartz job time out exception is  not thrown. There is no exception in logs.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the connection is stuck (network malfunction, firewall, ...) and hangs, the Quartz job never ends. It keeps occupying Quartz worker thread. I don't think there is any timeout built into Quartz - the job runs as long as it wants.

Since your job is stateful, Quartz won't start new triggers until the old finishes (that's the definition of stateful job).

The best thing you can do is apply some timeout to your SOAP call. It should be pretty straightforward.